# Imported JSON geometry not moving with bones

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, geometry, mesh

I have imported a model into my Three.js scene. I am able to move and rotate the bones but the model's geometry does not move with the bones.

Here is the code I have used to import the JSON file and add it to the scene,

```
/*load JSON file*/
// instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/wpdildine/wpdildine.github.com/master/models/cylinder.json', addModel );

var helpset;
var scaleVal = 3;

function addModel( geometry,  materials ){

    materials.skinning = true;

    var cs = scaleVal * Math.random();

    mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials) );

    scene.add(mesh);
    helpset = new THREE.SkeletonHelper(mesh);
    scene.add(helpset);     

}
```

The JSON file that I have imported includes weights so I did not think I had to add them myself. Would it be anything to do with binding the skeleton to the mesh?

Here is a link to my code - https://jsfiddle.net/joeob61k/1/ (New link with scripts, thanks @Mr. Polywhirl)

As you can see, 'Bone_2' in the GUI controls moves one of the bones but not the mesh.

EDIT: I have tried accessing the bones of the mesh in the render() function. I have done so by using the following line of code,

```
mesh.skeleton.bones[2].rotation = 0.1;
```

I get the following error: 'Cannot read property 'skeleton' of undefined(…)' were undefined is the mesh variable. Is there a new way of accessing the bones of a SkinnedMesh that I need to use?

Comment: I added the missing scripts to [your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joeob61k/1/) If anyone wants to work off of it.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl would you have any idea on how to solve this problem? Thanks for adding the scripts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the line,

```
materials.skinning = true;
```

It needs to be the following to work,

```
materials[0].skinning = true;
```